# .NET interfaces allowing implicit casts from non-derived types

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I was reading the Roslyn source code when I noticed [this](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CodeGen/EmitExpression.cs,2960) strange section:

```
    // Implicit casts are not emitted. As a result verifier may operate on a different 
    // types from the types of operands when performing stack merges in coalesce/ternary.
    // Such differences are in general irrelevant since merging rules work the same way
    // for base and derived types.
    //
    // Situation becomes more complicated with delegates, arrays and interfaces since they 
    // allow implicit casts from types that do not derive from them. In such cases
    // we may need to introduce static casts in the code to prod the verifier to the 
    // right direction
```

I'm curious of what would be needed for this to happen. I care in particular about when does an interface allow for an implicit cast from a non-derived type. However, an explanation for arrays/delegates would be interesting as well.

Comment: I think, that this comment talk about variance, which can be applied to delegates, arrays and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a classical example of Covariance in Generics: you can use the interface with the more generic class instead of the derived one.

So they

> "allow implicit casts from types that do not derive from them"

since here you have an implicit cast from the interface with the base type to the interface with the derived type, hence from types (the interfaces with base types) that do not derive from them (the interfaces with derived types).

In my example you can see a covariant interface that compute the area of a more derived shape as it were the less derived one, so you actually have a cast where - for example - a dimension is gone lost...

```
public class Basic 
{
    public double dim1;

}

public class Derived  : Basic
{
    public double dim2;
}


public interface IFactory<in T>
{
    double Area(T shape);
}

class BasicFactory : IFactory<Basic>
{
    public double Area(Basic shape)
    {
        return shape.dim1 * shape.dim1;
    }
}

class DerivedFactory : IFactory<Derived>
{
    public double Area(Derived shape)
    {
        return shape.dim1 * shape.dim2;
    }
}

class Program 
{
    double Area(IFactory<Derived> factory, Derived shape)
    {
        return factory.Area(shape);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IFactory<Basic> notDerived = new BasicFactory(); // from not derived type
        Derived shape = new Derived() { dim1 = 10, dim2 = 20 };
        double area = new Program().Area(notDerived,shape); // cast! dimension loss
        Console.WriteLine(area); // 100 = 10*10
        IFactory<Derived> derived = new DerivedFactory(); //from derived type
        area = new Program().Area(derived, shape); // no cast, now
        Console.WriteLine(area); // 200 = 10*20
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```